# Signals for a database view in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model in django that has the meta option `Managed=False` set. This model is a postgres view that get data from another schema. I would like to detect whenever the view changes (add/update/delete an object). I have tried using post_save from django.db.models.signals, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: You want a signal handler that listens to changes on the DB? Django signals are all triggered and handled in the application, if there’s no actual model being saved then there are no signals

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I want. Do you know of any way I can achieve this? It doesn't need to be solved with django.

Comment: You can use `LISTEN` on a PostgreSQL session and then run a callback whenever a  matching `NOTIFY` is triggered. You would need to implement DB triggers or similar to trigger the `NOTIFY`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-listen.html